# A man walks into a bar

Tags: lateral-thinking, humor

He asks for a glass of water. The bartender pulls out a shotgun and points it at him. The man says, thank you and leaves. Why did he thank him??

[Source](http://www.iriddler.com/riddles/puzzles/doors.htm)

Comment: I think this has too many possible answers, like many riddles of the"why did he?" kind. The solution is judged on being clever, not on fulfilling the conditions.

Comment: I think that this should be reopened.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The man had

> the hiccups.
>  Drinking water is one solution to cure hiccups, which is why the man asked for water.
>  Another solution is to be scared, and that's what the bartender did by pointing the shotgun at him.

Comment: Nice. Figured this one would be easy.

Answer (score 10):

The man felt threatened by the bartender's sudden and unprovoked hostility. He decided the safest course of action would be to leave very politely to avoid furthering angering the deranged barkeeper.

Comment: I didn't accept this is because it doesn't explain why he thanked him.

Comment: @JamesLynch He thanked the barman to avoid enraging him further. I think that's what xnor means by 'very politely'.

Comment: As opposed to my attitude when I get "sudden and unprovoked hostility" from a moderator, which is to pull out my own sidearm and defend myself.